# Define download path dotnetbrowser

Tags: download, path, dotnetbrowser

I use dotnetbrowser to display a web browser on a old windows framework.
have you an idea to define the download path ? 
My dotnetbroser is enable, i can show my webpage but i don't found in documentation or exemple how define this simple download path.

The only exemple that i've found is about the download event detection.
I use WPF in C#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `DotNetBrowser.DownloadItem.DestinationFile` property is writable and can be used to configure the path to store the file.

To set this property in your application, you need to subclass the `DotNetBrowser.DefaultDownloadHandler` and implement its `AllowDownload(DownloadItem)` method. Then you need to configure your download handler as shown in the documentation article: [File Download](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110026-file-downloads)

You can also configure and use `DotNetBrowser.WPF.WPFDefaultDownloadHandler` instance to show file chooser and select the path to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

- This is a solution

Défine your browser like variable :

```
BrowserView myBrowserView;
Browser myBrowser;
```

Create the browser properly :

```
this.myBrowser = BrowserFactory.Create();
this.myBrowserView = new WPFBrowserView(this.myBrowser);
```

Create event detection for download

```
this.myDowloadHandler = new SampleDownloadHandler();
this.myBrowser.DownloadHandler = myDowloadHandler;
```

Add it to a container, here, a grid

```
grid_navigateur.Children.Add((UIElement)myBrowserView.GetComponent());
```

Now we are going to use our "SampleDownloadHandler" class

```
class SampleDownloadHandler : DownloadHandler
{
    public bool AllowDownload(DownloadItem download)
    {
      download.DestinationFile = "exemple\of\path\whith\file\name";

        download.DownloadEvent += delegate(object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadItem downloadItem = e.Item;
            if (downloadItem.Completed)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Download complete");
            }
        };

        return true;
    }
```

My personalisated class define path and name of the file who is download and pop a message when is over.

(to found the file name, you do to cut the string download.DestinationFile after the last )